# How to solve "file is hidden" when doing git checkout in Jenkins within a CIFS share folder

Tags: git, jenkins, cifs

I set up a Jenkins server on linux, and mount Jenkins home to CIFS share folder. So everything is written into the CIFS shared folder.

But if I setup a job to checkout src with git, some files are disappeared(i.e., can't ls out, but in fact, it existed: if vim the disappeared file, it does has content in vim console).

I changed to windows's shared folder to check the disappeared files, they do exist!

Can anyone tell me what happened and how to fix it?

```sh
ls -al
...
SubsystemCapabilityService.java
SysGeneratorService.java
...
```

The file SysConfigService.java is NOT list out.

but when do: vim SysConfigService.java, in vim console, the file's content is shown!

I found if touch a new file named: SysConfigService-副本.java, then ls again:

```sh
ls -al
...
SubsystemCapabilityService.java
SysConfigService.java
SysGeneratorService.java
...
```

However, the file "SysConfigService-副本.java" is gone!